# Bar resolution and the morphisms define on $B_n$(free module)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Given a group extension $0\to K\to G\to Q\to 1$, we define $B_n$ as the free $\Bbb Z[Q]$-module on $Q^n$. And then we want to make a exact sequence $\cdots\to B_3\to B_2\to B_1\to B_0$, where the homomorphism between these $B_n$'s is $d_n$'s. And then the author define $d_3:B_3\to B_2$ as $d_3[x|y|z]=x[y|z]-[xy|z]+[x|yz]-[x|y]$. However, I feel weird that is such definition make sense? The domain of $d_3$ is $B_3$, which is isomorphic to $\oplus_{i\in Q^3}\Bbb Z[Q]$. And any element in $\oplus_{i\in Q^3}\Bbb Z[Q]$ is of the form $(\underbrace{\cdots\cdots}_{\text{has}~|Q^n|~\text{many component}})$. So how can $d_3$ be defined as $d_3[x|y|z]=x[y|z]-[xy|z]+[x|yz]-[x|y]$? It doesn't seem match.

[image]

Comment: There are $Q^3$ things of the form $[a|b|c]$. It doesn't matter how you write them, except this way is convenient for defining the boundaries.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Isn't every element in $B_3$ has $Q^3$ many components? Since $B_3=\oplus_{i\in Q^3}\Bbb Z[Q]$. Hmm..is my understanding of the definition of direct sum wrong? PS: As far as I know, $[a|b|c]=(a,b,c)$, hope that I didn't mistake it.

Comment: $[x|y] + [z|w]$ corresponds to what you would write as (0,...,0,1,0,...,0,1,0,...,0) if you were writing direct sums in that way